# Twilio TwilioRestClient does not contain a definition for SendSmsMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I'm trying to add Twilio for the SMS provider on my application, but I'm getting the following error on this line:

```
SendSmsMessage =>
twilio.**SendSmsMessage**(Keys.SMSAccountFrom, message.Destination, message.Body);
```

> TwilioRestClient does not contain a definition for SenSmsMessage and
>   no extension method SenSmsMessage accepting a first argument of type
>   TwilioRestClient coul be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

I'm working on visual Studio 2017, C#, Mvc 5, have installed Twilio 5.4.0 and Twilio.Asp.Mvc 5.1

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You say you have installed version 5.4.0 of the [Twilio C# library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp). However I think you are looking at the version 4.x documentation as `SendSmsMessage` is an old method.

You now need to use the new `MessageResource` object. Please check out the example below or the documentation for [sending messages here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp?code-sample=code-cnet-helper-library-example&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=default).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
            var accountSid = "AC81ebfe1c0b5c6769aa5d746121284056";
            // Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
            var authToken = "auth_token";   

            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            var message = MessageResource.Create(
                to: new PhoneNumber("+15558675309"),
                from: new PhoneNumber("+15017250604"),
                body: "Hello from C#");

            Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

It may be the case that Twilio.Asp.Mvc 5.1 hasn't got its version constraints correct and expects the version 4 library. So you may just need to pin Twilio back to version 4.7.2 and it will start working again.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your error message is a copy-and-paste from the original, then it looks like a simple typo in the method name: you have "SenSmsMessage", missing the 'd' from 'Send'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel Hume, the error message was not a copy and paste, I had to type it in, did not notice the typo.